# No sound on iOS 6 Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari, ios6, web-audio-api

I was really excited to see iOS 6 supports the Web Audio API, since we make HTML5 games.  However, I cannot get iOS 6 to play any sound at all using the Web Audio API with examples that work fine in desktop Chrome.

Here is a HTML5 game with touch controls and playing audio via the Web Audio API (if present - if not it will fall back to HTML5 audio):

http://www.scirra.com/labs/sbios6b/

*Edit: @Srikumar suggested some workarounds.  I applied them at the version below.  It still does not work!*

http://www.scirra.com/labs/sbios6f/

Everything plays just fine on desktop Chrome, but iOS 6 emits no sound at all.  I'm having trouble debugging it because I only do Windows development, and iOS 6 replaced the debug mode with remote web inspector, which apparently is not available on Safari for Windows.  Using a few alerts I did find it correctly identifies the Web Audio API, uses it, detects no Vorbis support so falls back to AAC audio, decodes a buffer and then plays it, and no errors are thrown, but I hear nothing.  And, of course, I tried turning the volume up to max :)

There should not be a codec problem, because iOS 6 can play AAC just fine - you can browse to [one of the .m4a's the game plays](http://www.scirra.com/labs/sbios6b/media/epicarpg.m4a) and it plays fine visited direct from Safari.

Looking at the Web Audio API examples here on iOS 6: http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/audio/samples.html - some of them work, and others don't.  For example, the [Chrome Audio Visualizer](http://www.htmlfivewow.com/demos/audio-visualizer/index.html) works, but [Javascript Drone](http://matt-diamond.com/drone.html) doesn't.

There must be some subtle incompatibility between Web Audio on iOS 6 and desktop Chrome.  What am I missing?

Comment: Could be related to file formats. I've had trouble with some mp3s in Safari.

Comment: Possibly, but as the post says I could play one of the .m4a sounds just fine directly from Safari.

Comment: Which ones specifically are you having issues with?

Comment: It looks to me like the currentTime of the audioContext doesn't update as it should. Just have to figure out why it does in some apps and not the others...

Comment: @OskarEriksson - the game example does not use currentTime on AudioContext, so I don't know why that would break it.  I'd have thought it's something else.

Comment: @AshleysBrain ah, ok. :) It does indicate that the context might not be rendering audio as it should, though. But it might not be related to this.

Comment: Weird!! I get the sounds on my iPhone4 with the "sbios6f" changes. Not sure whether it dropped to html5 audio, though. I'm beginning to suspect that the fact that my workaround works on my iPhone4 is just ... luck :)

Comment: Just a quick note: This example was not working for me on iPad3 and iOS6, just upgraded to iOS6.1 and it works! They must have fixed something.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**Edit (November 2015):** iOS 9 no longer allows audio to start in a `touchstart` event, which breaks the solution below. However it works in a `touchend` event. The original answer for iOS 6 is left intact below, but for iOS 9 support make sure you use `touchend`.

Well, sorry to answer my own bounty question, but after hours of debugging I finally found the answer.  Safari on iOS 6 effectively starts with the Web Audio API muted.  It will not unmute **until you attempt to play a sound in a user input event** (create a buffer source, connect it to destination, and call `noteOn()`).  After this, it unmutes and audio plays unrestricted and as it ought to.  This is an undocumented aspect of how the Web Audio API works on iOS 6 ([Apple's doc is here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds.html), hopefully they update it with a mention of this soon!)

The user can be touching the screen a lot, engaged in the game.  But it will remain muted.  You *have* to play inside a user input event like `touchstart` [edit: `touchend` for iOS 9+], once, then all audio unmutes.  After that you can play audio at any time (doesn't have to be in a user input event).

Note this is different to the restrictions on HTML5 audio: typically you can only start audio at all in a user input event, and only play one sound at a time; the Web Audio API fully unmutes after the first play-in-user-input, so that you can play sounds at any time, and then you can mix them polyphonically, process cool effects, etc.

This means many games already on the web using the Web Audio API will never play audio, because they do not happen to issue a noteOn in a touch event.  You have to adjust it to wait for the first user input event.

There are a few ways to work around this: don't play your title music until the user touches the screen; have an initial 'touch to enable audio' screen and play a sound then begin the game when they touch; etc.  Hopefully this will help anyone else having the same problem save some time trying to debug it!

Comment: Didn't both the previous answers state that an user action is required to get audio?

Comment: I read them as either implying you can only create the context there (not quite right) or that audio not triggered in a user action will never play (also not quite right)

Comment: _It will not unmute until you attempt to play a sound in a user input event_.


I have a counter example for this - http://srikumarks.github.com/demos/tala . (It is a kind of "metronome" for South Indian talas.) If you load that in Safari/iOS6/iPhone and just wait for a while, the metronome will start ticking away, although the graphics doesn't work the way it does in Chrome. No user input needed (except keying in the URL?).

Comment: I have found that you need to play a sound on a user event on the iPad but not iPhone. On the iPhone it appears to play automatically without any user input.

Comment: It is documented, just poorly: [User Control of Downloads Over Cellular Networks](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html)

Answer (score 7):

You can try to debug it using the Web Inspector on Safari 6 on a mac.

1. Enable "Webkit Inspector" in Mobile Safari settings/advanced.
2. Connect device to a Mac running Safari 6 using a USB cable.
3. Load your page/game
4. Go to menu Develop->[devicename]->[pageurl]

It doesn't work out of the box for me, but with a few tries it can help narrow down the problem.

Apparently there is also the thing that audio can only be triggered by a user action. I'm not sure this is true 'cos some code that works on iOS6 on iPhone4 doesn't play any sound on an iPad (also iOS6).

**Update**: Some success with web audio on iPhone4+iOS6. Found that the "currentTime" remains stuck at 0 for a while as soon as you create a new audio context on iOS6. In order to get it moving, you first need to perform a dummy API call (like `createGainNode()` and discard the result). Sounds play only when currentTime starts to run, but scheduling sounds exactly at currentTime doesn't seem to work. They need to be a little bit into the future (ex: 10ms). You can use the following `createAudioContext` function to wait until the context is ready to make noise. User action doesn't seem to be required on iPhone, but no such success on iPad just yet.

```
function createAudioContext(callback, errback) {
    var ac = new webkitAudioContext();
    ac.createGainNode(); // .. and discard it. This gets 
                         // the clock running at some point.

    var count = 0;

    function wait() {
        if (ac.currentTime === 0) {
            // Not ready yet.
            ++count;
            if (count > 600) {
                errback('timeout');
            } else {
                setTimeout(wait, 100);
            }
        } else {
            // Ready. Pass on the valid audio context.
            callback(ac); 
        }
    }

    wait();
}
```

Subsequently, when playing a note, don't call `.noteOn(ac.currentTime)`, but do `.noteOn(ac.currentTime + 0.01)` instead.

Please don't ask me *why* you have to do all that. That's just the way it is at the moment - i.e. crazy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very interesting.  Unfortunately it doesn't seem to apply to my first example.  Consider this demo made from scratch which works fine on an iPad 2 with iOS 6: http://www.scirra.com/labs/webaudio-ios6-working/ - it just uses noteOn(0) and doesn't use your "create gain node on startup" workaround.  There must be something else at work here...

Comment: The createGainNode() trick seemed to work for me - just make sure it is called in a callback from a touch event, and the restriction on sounds needing to be touch-triggered seems to disappear.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for--great solution!

Answer (score 5):

I managed to figure out a simple solution which I'm sure must have been documented elsewhere - but sometimes we have to spend hours figuring these things out for ourselves...

So it seems many tutorials (such as this one on [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/)) instruct you to do the following steps :

- Create an instance of `window.AudioContext` and if that doesn't exist (which it doesn't on iOS) then create `window.webkitAudioContext`.
- Create an `XMLHttpRequest` to load your sound file
- On the `load` event run `context.decodeAudioData(....)` and then `createBufferSource()`, filling it with the decoded data, and finally `source.start(0)` to play the sound.

As others have pointed out you must create the `AudioContext` (which incidentally you must store and use for the lifetime of the page) as a result of a user interaction (click or touchstart).

**HOWEVER :**
For iOS to 'unlock' its audio capabilities you  *MUST* have audio data available when you create the `AudioContext`. If you load the data asynchronously there's nothing for it to play. It is not sufficient to merely create the `AudioContext` inside a `click` event.

Here's two solutions for reliable iOS playback:

- 1) You must load at least one sound file before you even initialize the AudioContext, and then run all the above steps for that sound file immediately within a single user interaction (eg click).
- OR 2) Create a sound dynamically in memory and play it.

This is how I did that second option:

**REMEMBER - MUST BE within `click` / `touch` event for iOS:**

```
 window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
 var context = new window.AudioContext();

 // you should null check window.AudioContext for old browsers to not blow up

 // create a dummy sound - and play it immediately in same 'thread'
 var oscillator = context.createOscillator();
 oscillator.frequency.value = 400;
 oscillator.connect(context.destination);
 oscillator.start(0);
 oscillator.stop(.5);    // you can set this to zero, but I left it here for testing.

 // audio context is now 'unlocked' and ready to load and play sounds asynchronously
 // YOU MUST STORE 'context' for future usage. DON'T recreate more AudioContexts
```

I imagine this is a common mistake - and I'm surprised after 3 years that nobody seems to have pointed this out or discovered it :-/

Comment: Also works when put into a function that is called from an event handler. Awesome!

Answer (score 3):

So, I think I've figured it out.

It's a issue of Apple requiring an user action before sound can be allowed to play. It turns out, at least for me, that you shouldn't create the audio context at all except when the user calls for it. It's not enough to create the context when the page loads and then use createGainNode or similar on an user action.

In your case I'd create the context when the user clicks the "Touch to begin" button.

Comment: I don't think it's that - this example creates the audio context on startup and it works OK: http://www.scirra.com/labs/webaudio-ios6-working/ I also tried playing the sounds themselves on a timer (as in, not in a user input event) and it worked.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it works ok. The original game, though, looks like it has some errors at the moment. I'm getting this when entering on the iPad: 
    "sbios6b:9 - Viewport argument key "target-densitydpi" not recognized and ignored."
    "c2runtime.js:5534 - SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12: An invalid or illegal string was specified."

Answer (score 1):

Answering to the *original* question, I can confirm some troubles with file formats on iPhone 4S/iOS 6 and MacOSX. If an MP3 file is "not good" for Safari, the decoding goes bad and calling AudioContext.createBuffer(array, bool) gives you and error.

The strange thing is about the error: "SYNTAX_ERR, DOM Exception 12", as pointed out by others. This makes me think it is a bug....

Same behavior also on MacOS, with Safari 6.0 (7536.25).

Answer (score 1):

I have come across the audio restrictions with **HTML5 Audio** on iOS and worked around the problem by:

1) Creating an Audio Element with a silent audio file and playing it initially with a touch event (e.g. 'begin game' button) and then immidietly pausing it.

2) Building a sound-switcher function which switches the Audio src and then plays the Audio element after a short timeout.

3) Calling the sound-switcher function on any events (doesn't need to be a touch event).

This works because the Audio Element is un-muted on first touch, with the silent audio file, and remains un-muted, so the source can be switched on-the-fly.

```
switchSound: (id) ->
        @soundSwitch.pause()
        @soundSwitch.src = @sounds[id]._src

        clearTimeout @switchSoundDelay
        @switchSoundDelay = setTimeout =>
            # @soundSwitch.volume = 1
            @soundSwitch.play()
        ,50
```

Answer (score 1):

**updated for 2015 solution:**
hey all, if you are here working on a web audio problem with ios6+ I've found these links as help.

-this is a good article with code solution: http://matt-harrison.com/perfect-web-audio-on-ios-devices-with-the-web-audio-api/

-here is an update to the api after the above ^ solution article was written https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Porting_webkitAudioContext_code_to_standards_based_AudioContext

-below is my updated solution to the first article, using the changes from the second article. The issue I was having was iOS 7 safari throwing a strange not-enough-args error. this fixed it:

```
define(function() {

  try {
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    window.audioContext = new window.AudioContext();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("No Web Audio API support");
  }
/*
 * WebAudioAPISoundManager Constructor
 */
 var WebAudioAPISoundManager = function (context) {
  this.context = context;
  this.bufferList = {};
  this.playingSounds = {};
};

/*
 * WebAudioAPISoundManager Prototype
 */
 WebAudioAPISoundManager.prototype = {
   addSound: function (url) {
      // Load buffer asynchronously
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("GET", url, true);
      request.responseType = "arraybuffer";

      var self = this;

      request.onload = function () {
        // Asynchronously decode the audio file data in request.response
        self.context.decodeAudioData(
          request.response,

          function (buffer) {
            if (!buffer) {
              alert('error decoding file data: ' + url);
              return;
            }
            self.bufferList[url] = buffer;
          });
      };

      request.onerror = function () {
        alert('BufferLoader: XHR error');
      };

      request.send();
    },
    stopSoundWithUrl: function(url) {
      if(this.playingSounds.hasOwnProperty(url)){
        for(var i in this.playingSounds[url]){
          if(this.playingSounds[url].hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            this.playingSounds[url][i].stop(0);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

/*
 * WebAudioAPISound Constructor
 */
 var WebAudioAPISound = function (url, options) {
  this.settings = {
    loop: false
  };

  for(var i in options){
    if(options.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      this.settings[i] = options[i];
    }
  }

  this.url = '/src/www/assets/audio/' + url + '.mp3';
  this.volume = 1;
  window.webAudioAPISoundManager = window.webAudioAPISoundManager || new WebAudioAPISoundManager(window.audioContext);
  this.manager = window.webAudioAPISoundManager;
  this.manager.addSound(this.url);
    // this.buffer = this.manager.bufferList[this.url];
  };

/*
 * WebAudioAPISound Prototype
 */
 WebAudioAPISound.prototype = {
  play: function () {
    var buffer = this.manager.bufferList[this.url];
    //Only play if it's loaded yet
    if (typeof buffer !== "undefined") {
      var source = this.makeSource(buffer);
      source.loop = this.settings.loop;
        source.start(0);

        if(!this.manager.playingSounds.hasOwnProperty(this.url)) {
          this.manager.playingSounds[this.url] = [];
        }
        this.manager.playingSounds[this.url].push(source);
      }
    },
    stop: function () {
      this.manager.stopSoundWithUrl(this.url);
    },
    getVolume: function () {
      return this.translateVolume(this.volume, true);
    },
    //Expect to receive in range 0-100
    setVolume: function (volume) {
      this.volume = this.translateVolume(volume);
    },
    translateVolume: function(volume, inverse){
      return inverse ? volume * 100 : volume / 100;
    },
    makeSource: function (buffer) {
      var source = this.manager.context.createBufferSource();
      var gainNode = this.manager.context.createGain();
      source.connect(gainNode);
      gainNode.gain.value = this.volume;
      source.buffer = buffer;
      // source.connect(gainNode);
      gainNode.connect(this.manager.context.destination);
      return source;
    }
  };

  return WebAudioAPISound;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: iOS still requires a user input to play sound ([No sound on iOS 6 Web Audio API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517000/no-sound-on-ios-6-web-audio-api/12569290#12569290))

I was previously stuck with web audio on iOS web. And to make things worse, it needs to work on android and other desktop platform. This post is one of those posts that I read and found no immediate answers.

Until I found [howler.js](https://howlerjs.com).

This is the solution for cross-platform web audio solution:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/howler/2.0.3/howler.min.js"></script>

<script>

  var sound = new Howl({
    src: ['yay3.mp3']
  });
  sound.play();


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an actual answer, just a direction to look if things still aren't working.  iOS6 has audio issues on *some* devices (particularly the 64gb 4s manufactured during a particular period, though I've seen others so it may not actually be hardware related) and will mysteriously stop playing some kinds of sounds (not ringtones or voice, for some reason, but many other sounds), and it's volume sliders will vanish.  I've found it notoriously difficult to debug as it will usually (thought not always, sometimes you can catch it) happen only when not connected with a power cord.

Look in the console for ASSERTION FAILURE messages from the VirtualAudio_Device and with various codecs.  This may have nothing whatsoever to do with your particular issue, but then again, a bug in one area of the sound device may be related to another.  At minimum, it's an area to investigate if nothing else is helping.

Answer (score 0):

The API appears to be broken on iOS 6.1, or at least, has a breaking change that means no sites currently work with it.

Answer (score 0):

I've got trouble using all simple solutions. Especially, when I want to play a sound multiple times.

So I'm using this js library: http://pupunzi.open-lab.com/2013/03/13/making-html5-audio-actually-work-on-mobile

Answer (score 0):

Okay I like AshleysBrain answer, it helped me to solve the problem.  But I found a bit more general solution.

Before you had to initiate the play sound from a user event, now they force you to do it via a user input event, (sounds strange)  What I did was just read a input field before I played the sound.

So

```
  $('#start-lesson').click(function() {
  return startThisLesson();
});
startThisLesson = function() {
     var value;
     value = $('#key-pad-value')[0].value;
     playSoundFile(yourBuffer);
}
```

playSoundFile is whatever you use to create the buffer source.