# SoundManager won't play after HTML5 app cache loads, only after refresh on iOS

Tags: ios, html, html5-appcache, soundmanager2

On iOS I have an issue with sounds not playing the first time after I load the HTML5 app cache. However after a page refresh it works fine. In debug mode I get only these 2 entries:
[Log] sound0: loadstart 
[Log] sound0: suspend

I'm using http://www.schillmania.com soundManager2 and I'm not experiencing this issue on the desktop version of Safari.
In my webInspector on iOS I can see that all my sounds have been loaded in the app cache. But for some strange reason I still see get requests in my server log.

Anyone have some idea's on how I can troubleshoot this? 
And is it known if soundManager plays well with Safari' HTML5 app cache?

I've also asked this question on Schillmania's website, but was still wondering if any devs here have any experience with this also.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517000/no-sound-on-ios-6-web-audio-api - this is probably what you are hitting

Comment: Thanks, I tricked it already by calling user input event that runs a function that should play the sound but that didn't help either. It looks like soundManger isn't even trying to access the files from my appcache even though they're all present in the app cache. That's why I see get requests on the server still.