# Audio never loads on iPad but it works perfect on emulator - PhoneGap + Howler.js

Tags: ios, cordova, html5-audio, howler.js

I am using [Howler.js](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js) on my PhoneGap application. Because my audio files are large (more than 10Mb) im an setting the buffer attribute to true (forcing HTML5 Audio).

```
var theSound = new Howl({
  urls: ['assets/Sound.m4a'],
  buffer: true,
  sprite: {
    scene0 : [ 1966000, 27000] }
```

When I test my application on the emulator and my iPad Mobile Safari everything works well. But when I run the application on the iPad as an app, the audio never starts. Using the web inspector I have noted that the audio file tries to load again and again like an not ending loop. You can see an attached screenshot of the resources tab on the web inspector both both the emulator and the iPad, running the same PhoneGap app.

[image]

Any idea on what could be the problem?

Comment: I have a similar problem but on the iPad 3 with iOS7. Sometimes it loads and sometimes not. Also it seems a little stressful to the safari browser. Any solutions yet? I'm using only mp3's.

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking into this for a while.

From what I've gathered, Howler defaults to Web Audio API, and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12569290/1277651) says you need a "user input event" to make it work on iOS, because by default it mutes everything. **I even tried Howler's own interactive demo on my iPad 2 with iOS 5 (I still haven't updated) [here](http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/104/howler.js-Modern-Web-Audio-Javascript-Library) and NONE OF THE SOUNDS WORK**.  My first link has a link to Apple's documentation, and I haven't tried it yet, but it looks like the convenience of Howler has to be replaced with a lower level implementation that takes about 5-10 lines with XMLHTTPRequest (see the Apple link), or another more versatile library. I'm still learning about what exactly I need, but I have a very similar problem I've been working on resolving today.

But then Howler falls back to HTML5 Audio. OK so I'm just googling that now, and this [link comes up](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ioshtml5/), and it's just reminding me of the pletora of compatibility considerations between OGG ACC MP3 etc on various browsers vs. browser layout engines vs. operating systems. So I'm left believing your file format M4A, related to MP3 as far as I can tell, isn't working in the target brower on the target iPad OS. I'm not familiar enough yet to give exact specifics but certainly since Howler doesn't work on my iPad that proves there's at least a problem with that.

The whole point I chose Howler to use was to abstract all the above away! I'm going to go look for another more comprehensive library now =D

Comment: So I proved audio works with onclick event, see [Apple's link here](  https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html). It's a business decision per [this SO post's replies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009888/autoplay-audio-files-on-an-ipad-with-html5). I'm going to try finding a way to trigger an onclick event, since I never wanted typical style buttons, but I have a strong feeling I'll be stuck with them. Hope these help.

Answer (score 3):

the problem might be file size.  IPad has a limited cache memory size and if you overflow it assets will not work.  The only solution to this problem is smaller file size.  Another possibility is html audio will not load or play except in a user event (touch).  Web Audio will load but starts muted and only unmutes with a play call inside of a user event.

[SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS) is a library I help develop that handles as much of this stuff as possible.  In particular I think you would find the [Mobile Safe Approach](http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Mobile%20Safe%20Approach/) useful.  It is well tested on iOS and Android devices.  Unfortunately we do not support sound sprites yet.

Hope that helps.

Comment: By the by, SoundJS has added support for sound sprites.