# HTML5 mobile: Play only one side of audio from a video stream on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, html, audio, web-audio-api

I am trying to play a video on iOS while listening to only one side of the stereo audio.

Code below works fine on desktop Chrome but not on Safari on iPhone5 with 8.3 iOS.

```
var AudioContext = window.webkitAudioContext;
  var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
  var splitter = audioCtx.createChannelSplitter(2);
  var merger = audioCtx.createChannelMerger(1);

  source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(video);
  source.connect(splitter);
  splitter.connect(merger, 0); 
  merger.connect(audioCtx.destination);
```

'video' is the reference to the DOM video element.

Any help would be much appreciated

thanks, a lot

Sa'ar

Comment: Can you check on IOS if it's the `window.AudioContext` or the `window.webkitAudioContext` which is loaded ?

Comment: Safari uses window.webkitAudioContext

Answer (score 0):

Here is a polyfill that checks whether Web audio exists and whether to use `-webkit` or not.

```
//borrowed from underscore.js
function isUndef(val){
    return val === void 0;
}

if (isUndef(window.AudioContext)){
    window.AudioContext = window.webkitAudioContext;
} 

if (!isUndef(AudioContext)){
    audioContext = new AudioContext();
} else {
    throw new Error("Web Audio is not supported in this browser");
}
```

Also there is a similar IOS error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517000/no-sound-on-ios-6-web-audio-api/12569290#12569290) that might help.

Answer (score -1):

Check what kind of audio context the device uses instead of using `||`.  For example:

```
var AudioContext 
if('webkitAudioContext' in window) {
   AudioContext = new webkitAudioContext();
}
else{
   AudioContext = new AudioContext ();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of that, but he is looking for cross browser compatibility so both should be supported

Comment: thnx. updated the question since only iOS concerns me.