# Web Audio API demo doesn't work on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, web-audio-api

I'm currently working on adapting this [web audio API demo](http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/MIDIDrums/index.html) for a project that I am working on, but there is no sound when I test on an iPhone. It works fine on the iPad.

I've searched for solutions and found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517000/no-sound-on-ios-6-web-audio-api/12569290#12569290) on StackOverflow with the following snippet of one of the answers:

> Safari on iOS 6 effectively starts with the Web Audio API muted. It
>   will not unmute until you attempt to play a sound in a user input
>   event (create a buffer source, connect it to destination, and call
>   noteOn()). After this, it unmutes and audio plays unrestricted and as
>   it ought to. This is an undocumented aspect of how the Web Audio API
>   works on iOS 6 (Apple's doc is here, hopefully they update it with a
>   mention of this soon!)

The user input event should be the onclick event on the play button but changing to use `noteOn()` instead of `start()` still doesn't fix it.

**Update:** I've also tried binding the play button with the `touchend` event but to no avail.

Here is the function that uses noteOn():

```
function playNote(buffer, pan, x, y, z, sendGain, mainGain, playbackRate, noteTime) {
    // Create the note
    var voice = context.createBufferSource();
    voice.buffer = buffer;
    voice.playbackRate.value = playbackRate;

    // Optionally, connect to a panner
    var finalNode;
    if (pan) {
        var panner = context.createPanner();
        panner.panningModel = "HRTF";
        panner.setPosition(x, y, z);
        voice.connect(panner);
        finalNode = panner;
    } else {
        finalNode = voice;
    }

    // Connect to dry mix
    var dryGainNode = context.createGain();
    dryGainNode.gain.value = mainGain * effectDryMix;
    finalNode.connect(dryGainNode);
    dryGainNode.connect(masterGainNode);

    // Connect to wet mix
    var wetGainNode = context.createGain();
    wetGainNode.gain.value = sendGain;
    finalNode.connect(wetGainNode);
    wetGainNode.connect(convolver);

    if (iOS) {        
        voice.noteOn(noteTime);    
    }
    else {
        voice.start(noteTime);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: I've added the function that calls the noteOn() but the codebase is quite large. The project is on Github at https://github.com/cwilso/MIDIDrums

Comment: The original demo is here and it doesn't work on the iPhone either. http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/MIDIDrums/index.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I feel really stupid. Apparently, if you have your iPhone on vibrate mode, the sound doesn't play.

Comment: This answer just saved me hours and hours of fruitless debugging. Thanks!

Comment: I found this answer _after_ hours and hours of fruitless debugging. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The start() method should work fine without the if else statements on iOS as long as you call the function with a user interaction event. Also flip the order you pass y and z to the panner cause z is second for some strange reason.
Here's a working example, change stuff in it to fit what you need, most isn't need and I've got others somewhere that use the dom to add event listeners

```
<script>
    var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();
    var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
    oscillator.connect(gainNode); 
    gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    oscillator.type = 'sine'; 
    oscillator.frequency.value = 440;

    gainNode.gain.value = 1;
</script>
<button onclick="oscillator.start();">play</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll remove that logic and fix the y and z. Here is the method that uses the playNote() function to bind the play button: 
document.getElementById('play').addEventListener('touchend', handlePlay, true);

Answer (score 0):

My own experience has been that sometimes the Web Audio API works on iPhones, sometimes it doesn't. Here is a page that worked 5 minutes ago on my iPhone 6s; 1 minute ago it didn't work; now it does again!

http://www.stephenandrewtaylor.net/dna-sonification/

Here is another one that works intermittently; it worked 2 minutes ago and now it doesn't (the animations work, there is just no audio).

http://www.stephenandrewtaylor.net/lie-sonification/

It might have to do with how many tabs are open in Safari; you could try closing some of your open tabs (right now I have 5 tabs, including the lie-sonificaton page which worked 2 minutes ago but now doesn't). I am also a novice programmer and I'm sure there are much better ways I could be writing the code.